# Best way to use PHP srt_replace to replace content only denoted by the first few chars with varying lengths?

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the best way to use **srt_replace** to replace content that is only denoted by the first few characters and may have varying lengths?  I am attempting to make a change to how WordPress auto embeds images with Add Media.  Based on the image I would like to remove the hard coded width value and replace it with a different value.

I could approach this with a loop looking for the string `width` and then look for the next space.  Then use these start and end values to remove the width param and value.  But it seems like there might be a "shorthand" way to do this type of find and replace?

The below code would work if I knew the width was exactly "321", but how can I find any value for `width` and replace it with `width=100%`?  The value following width could have any number of characters. I assume the answer will be `height` with a small change.

```
$<a href="http://img.png">
    <img src="http://dev.x.com/wordpress/wp-content/321x205.png" width="100%" height="205">
</a>
$correctwidth = str_replace('width="321" ', 'width="100%" ', $html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Preg_replace to do this:

```
$html = "width=\"300\" height=\"205\"";
echo preg_replace("#width=\"[\d+]+\"#", 'width="100%"', $html);
```

It will return width="100%" height="205"

[Test here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa77bd7541e9b98708c3dca4fec3841b3e730860)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the easiest answer is to use Javascript/jQuery:

```
 $('img').each(function(){ 
   $(this).removeAttr('width')
   $(this).removeAttr('height');
});
```

and then CSS

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```